# Is it possible to access GAE datastore without an http request?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Is it possible to access GAE datastore without making an appengine context out of a http request?
I want to be able to access the datastore in separate threads that do not have access to the app engine context.  is this possible? or should i try to find a work around?
the language im working in is Go btw...

EDIT: More info
The reason i can't use pass all the appengine contexts down to the level needed is because im building a chat server with multiple threads.  Once the main port listening thread is started, with the one instance of a context, it keeps that context around for the duration of the thread.  However, after that thread starts, there can be many more connections to the server all of which cant pass through a context because the port listener is already started.  The reason i need the context passed all the way through is because i need to be able to log messages in the client read handler.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but GAE provides a [remote api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) which gives you the ability to interact with your service. I am sure its provided for Python and Java versions.

Comment: This looks like it would work if i was using Python... unfortunately, the rest of my server is in Go, and from the looks of it, the Go tools doesn't seem to have this feature yet...

Comment: If you are brave enough you can re-write the logic of your Go web app to python with [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com)

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need an `appengine.Context` (and therefore the request) for  any datastore access. Fortunately the request should be easy enough to pass to whatever part of your code requires it.

I'm not sure what `appengine_internal` does with the context, but the context itself can be passed back and forth as required. Maybe a code example would be a good next step if you don't think this will work for you?